# c++ named elements in container

Tags: c++, object, containers

I have a bunch of gases, each with some attributes, such as density, atomic mass, etc. Basically I want to have a container, to which I can add named gasses with easy access in my program. I can sort of do this using classes as:

```
class gases 
{
    class gas
    {
        double mass;
        double density;
    };

gas h2o;
gas co2;
};
```

I guess it might be preferred to do this with derived classes? I.e derive h2o from a base class gas? But I'm not entirely sure how to implement that, also I don't think it is what I'm looking for. The thing I'm unhappy with is solution is that I have to declare all my gases already in the class definition. It'd be more intuitive to me to do something like (in pseudo-code):

```
object gas (mass,density)
container gases
gases.append(h2o(m,rho))

cout << "the atomic mass of water is" << gases.h2o.mass << endl;
```

That is, I'm looking for *a container to which I can add named objects*.

Another unsatisfactory solution is to make a vector of gas objects, but then I'd have to remember the order in which I added the gases.

Comment: Sounds like you want an associative container like [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: `std::map<std::string,gas> gases;` should work. Maybe give a better definition what exactly you mean with _"named objects"_.

Comment: Yes, `std::map` seems to be doing what I'm looking for, thanks. A meta question though: Why did this question get instant down voted? I'm not saying it shouldn't be, I just want to understand why, so I can pose better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking for a dynamic container so that you can add and remove gasses or just want to keep it tidy. If the latter, maybe you can try something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

struct gasses
{
    struct hydrogen
    {
        static double const mass;
        static double const density;
    };

    struct helium
    {
        static double const mass;
        static double const density;
    };
};

double const gasses::hydrogen::mass = 1.00794;
double const gasses::hydrogen::density = 0.000089;
double const gasses::helium::mass = 4.002602;
double const gasses::helium::density = 0.00018;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "The density of helium is: " << std::fixed << gasses::helium::density << " g/mL" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
The density of helium is: 0.00018 g/mL
```

Comment: This works, `std::map` also works. I don't know which one is to prefer in situations such as these, but this is definitively an answer to my question. Thanks